# How to run Live backup of Virttual Machines - Libvirt-Qemu

Tags: linux, backup, qemu, libvirt

im Trying to run this script

```
https://gogs.tausys.de/shogun/libvirt-imagebackup/raw/master/backup-vms.sh
```

When i run it, it starts like this.

```
Wed, 16 Oct 2019 12:44:59 +0200 Backup KVM online guest 'ubuntu16.04'
Domain snapshot backup created
/usr/bin/backup-vms.sh: line 241: /backupDisk/VMs/ubuntu16.04/domain.xml: No such file or directory
Wed, 16 Oct 2019 12:45:00 +0200 Backup KVM of 'ubuntu16.04' complete
Wed, 16 Oct 2019 12:45:00 +0200 Backup done
Wed, 16 Oct 2019 12:45:00 +0200 -----------
```

when i check for the results i see that the snapshot is made. ubuntu16.04.qcow.backup buut when i check the Folder /backupDisk/ there is no xml file and there ist neither a backup file, in the root folder from libvirt i see both files backup and original, what means that blockcommit was not executed.

does anyone can help? 
thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the newest version of the backupscript? I had this problem because I used an older version. In libvirt 5.x there where some small changes in a command. Or when you have an older version of libvirt as 5.x maybe you shoud use an older version of the backup script

Comment: ok i will try with an older version. cuz im on linux 18 LTS and the higher update i got vor libvirt is 4.x. or is it possible to add the sources for linux 19 and then upgrade just libvirt? thanks!

Comment: i woud prefere to use an older version of the backup script instead of use other sources in ubuntu. Maybe there are alot of dependencies for libvirt